# Use of _ in bash find command

Tags: shell-script, find

What is the function of the underscore (`_`) in the `find` command below which is a command to create a file in all directories?

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'echo "nameofyourwebsite" > "$1"' _ {}/downloaded.txt \;
```

And if  `{}` is a placeholder that is holding the directory names then why is the `echo` command redirecting to `$1`?

Please explain in the simplest way how this command is working.

Comment: [What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690)

Comment: See also [Is it possible to use \`find -exec sh -c\` safely?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010)

Comment: `find . -type d -exec sh -c 'for file do echo nameofyourwebsite > "$file/downloaded.txt"; done' sh {} +` would be standard, more portable and more efficient (and also avoid that bad practice of  using `_` for `$0` here).

Comment: Looks like a typo to me.

Comment: Please do not cross post, as you have [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71630915/use-of-underscore-in-bash-find-command)